# simplify complex logical condition in python

Tags: python, if-statement

How can I simplify this complex logical condition?

For a much shorter and more readable code

```
if i < 13:
    linux0[j] = query_res
elif 13 <= i < 27:
    linux1[j] = query_res
elif 27 <= i < 28:
    linux2[j] = query_res
elif 28 <= i < 33:
    linuxDnsServer1[j] = query_res
elif 33 <= i < 41:
    linuxRadius[j] = query_res
elif 41 <= i < 46:
    gen[j] = query_res
elif 46 <= i < 49:
    cdu[j] = query_res
elif 49 <= i < 55:
    avalanche[j] = query_res
elif 55 <= i < 69:
    defensePro_devices[j] = query_res
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear that it's more understandable, but you can put the limits and lists in another list, and iterate over it;

```
targets = [(12, linux0), (26, linux1), (27, linux2), (32, linuxDnsServer1),
           (40, linuxRadius), (45, gen), (48, cdu), (54, avalanche), (68, defensePro_devices)]
for limit, target in targets:
    if i <= limit:
        target[j] = query_res
        break
```

Comment: To add: 1) If you need non-consecutive intervals, you can swap the limits with explicit `range` objects and then use  `if i in interval` in place of `if i <= limit`. 2) You can also add an `else` branch at the end of the `for` to handle the case where no match is found (i.e. when the `break` statement is never reached)

Comment: I was going to put #2 in, but since the original code doesn't print an error, I left it out.

Comment: Another way to handle non-consecutive intervals is to use an extra list for the gaps.